how to access dynamic field data in elasticsearch query in logstash filter
I have below logstash filter conf-
filter {
 mutate {
    add_field => {"attribute" => "%{[database_result][name]}" }
    }
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    user => "elastic"
    password => "EEdg3DlF=OYX1Dct9fpW"
    index => "users"
    ssl => "false"
    query_template => "template.json"
     fields => {
    "%{[database_result][name]}" => "es_attribute"
    "userName" => "user_name"
    "timezone" => "timezone"
    "state" => "state"
    "postalCode" => "postalCode"
    "country" => "country"
}  
  }

Template.json file(query is working and getting results but dynamic field value is not coming)-
{
 "sort" : [ { "_doc" : "desc" } ],  
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*",
      "fields": [
          "%{[database_result][name]}"
        ]
    }
  }
}

below is the result I'm getting for dynamic fields:
 "es_attribute" => nill

when I uses hardcoded values in fields like-
 fields => {
        "dynamic_attributes_xyz1234" => "es_attribute"
        "userName" => "user_name"
        "timezone" => "timezone"
        "state" => "state"
        "postalCode" => "postalCode"
        "country" => "country"
    }  

I'm getting results for that field-
"es_attribute" => "dynamic"

please let me know what I'm doing wrong in the above code.
